# How can I set a default value for a dependency property of type derived from dependencyobject?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am new to WPF and this is my first post. I have created a class called 'Fruit' that descends from 'DependencyObject' and adds and extra property called 'Apple'.

I have created a new custom control that includes a Dependency Property called 'MyFruit' of type 'Fruit'.

How can I set the default value for the properties within 'MyFruit' object (i.e. the 'Apple' property? I would like to set this in XAML using the <Setter> object.

```
public class Gauge : Control
{
    .
    .
    .

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------
    #region MyFruit Dependency Property

    public Fruit MyFruit
    {
        get { return (Fruit)GetValue(MyFruitProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyFruitProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyFruitProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyFruit", typeof(Fruit), typeof(CircularGauge), null);

    #endregion


}


//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
#region Fruit class

public class Fruit : DependencyObject
{
    private int apple;

    public int Apple
    {
        get { return apple; }
        set { apple = value; }
    }

 }

#endregion
```

Answer (score 47):

Instead of null in your dependency property metadata, insert

```
new UIPropertyMetadata("YOUR DEFAULT VALUE GOES HERE")
```

So now it becomes:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyFruitProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("MyFruit", typeof(Fruit), typeof(CircularGauge), new UIPropertyMetadata("YOUR DEFAULT VALUE GOES HERE"));
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but i would like to know how to set the 'Apple'property in XAML using the setter if possible?

Comment: "Your Default Value Goes Here" How does this exactly work? Metadate default value must be a value type. But I need to set a default value for sub-properties in 'Fruit' class which is a reference type?

Comment: yes you are right...You can define the default value through the TargetNullValue property.

<TextBox Text="{Binding Apple, TargetNullValue=DefaultValue }" />

Comment: Thanks I must try 'TargetNullValue'. But I think that I have found another solution. If i create a resource <local:Fruit x:Key="DefaultFruit" Apple="5"/> and then in my style I can use the setter. <Setter Property="MyFruit" Value="{StaticResource DefaultFruit}"/> This solution worked for me

Comment: For future readers landing here, check Rick's answer in [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850859/how-to-set-default-value-of-dependencyproperty-of-a-type-derived-from-dependency). Had it not been there, I'd have fewer hair on my head.

Answer (score 8):

You need to use `PropertyMetaData` like this:

```
class MyValidation
{
    public bool status
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(statusProperty); }
        set { SetValue(statusProperty, value); }
    }
    
    public static readonly DependencyProperty statusProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("status", typeof(bool), typeof(MyValidation),new PropertyMetadata(false));
}
```